# How do I fix this "assignment" in google-apps-script?

Tags: google-apps-script

So I started editing this code so I can make it create words. Eventually making a replication of Alan Turing's Bombe. However after my last edit my "assignment" became invalid? Now I am confused, especially since I am not 100% familiar with google-apps-script.

Here is what my current script currently says:

```
function bombeCode2() {

  var fastRotor = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N",
    "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z"
  ];

  var mediumRotor = fastRotor;
  var slowRotor = fastRotor;

  var rows = 26;
  var columns = 26;

  for (var i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
    Logger.log('Outer Loop: value of i : ' + i);
    // Logger.log("Partition for Outer Loop");
    // Logger.log(" ");
    var fastRotorValue = fastRotor[i];

    for (var j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
      Logger.log('-Inner Loop value of j : ' + j);
      //var fastRotorValue = fastRotor[i];
      var medRotorValue = mediumRotor[j];

      // Logger.log("---- " + fastRotorValue + " " + medRotorValue);

      for (var k = 0; k < 26; k++) {
        // Logger.log('---- XXXX Third Loop value of k : ' + k);
        //var fastRotorValue = fastRotor[i];
        //var medRotorValue = mediumRotor[j];
        var slowRotorValue = slowRotor[k];
        if ("---- XXXX " + fastRotorValue + " " + medRotorValue + " " + slowRotorValue = "WEATHER") {
          Logger.log("---- XXXX " + fastRotorValue + " " + medRotorValue + " " + slowRotorValue = "WEATHER")
        }
        // Logger.log("---- XXXX " + fastRotorValue + " " + medRotorValue + " " + slowRotorValue);
      };

      //var objectNumberValuePair = {"0":"A", "1":"B", "2":"C","3":"D","4":"E","5":"F","6":"G","7":"H","8":"I",
      //  "9":"J","10":"K","11":"L","12":"M","13":"N","14":"O","15":"P","16":"Q","17":"R",
      //  "18":"S","19":"T","20":"U","21":"V","22":"W","23":"X","24":"Y","25":"Z"}
      //  Logger.log(slowRotorValue = objectNumberValuePair); 
      //  Logger.log(medRoterValue = objectNumberValuePair);
      //  Logger.log(fastRoterValue = objectNumberValuePair);
    }

  }
}
```

Yes I know that half of it is useless as is. However this is only so I can remember what everything is/does.
Does anyone know how to fix this "assignment?" Here is the error message it gives me *"Invalid assignment left-hand side. (line 1, file "B. Test 2")."*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing a variable assignment in an if-statement.

Try using valid js-syntax:

```
   var compareValue = "---- XXXX " + fastRotorValue + " " + medRotorValue + " " + slowRotorValue;
    if (compareValue === "WEATHER"){
               Logger.log(compareValue + ' === "WEATHER"');
    }
```

Comment: I would give you +1 but "don't have enough reputation" to do so. So thank you! I didn't think about creating new variable.

Comment: I didn't know how otherwise I wouldn't have done it sooner. I didn't see the check-mark until I switched computers.